# WPF DataTemplate specify an alternative source

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I have a `DataTemplate` which is based on an `XmlNode`.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="person" >
    <Border Margin="30" CornerRadius="25">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=[dog], Source={????}}" />
        </Border.Background>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@forename}" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I then have a `ContentControl` in my `Window` which has its `Content`set to an `XmlNode` with an element name of 'person' and an attribute name of 'forename'.

This all works fine, but I now want to apply an alternative `Source` for the `Border` background image.

I have a class which 'feeds' the uri of an image, after ensuring that the image is available. This class is called `ResourceLoader` and it works perfectly in any control that's in my main window, but I can't work out how to refer to it from my `DataTemplate`.

The `ResourceLoader` is the main `DataContext` of the `Window`.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I think I've solved this.

I've added a new item to my `Resources`

```
<local:ResourceLoader x:Key="allimages" />
```

Then, in my `ImageBrush` I'm specifying...

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource allimages}, Path=[dog]}" />
```

Problem solved.